# Flutter for web, print function is not working with VS Code on windows

Tags: flutter

I used flutter run -d chrome to run the app, but dart's print doesn't work properly with VS Code in windows. I looked for solutions from another issue, but the problem still exists.

But, it will work fine on android debug.

````
$ flutter doctor -v

[√] Flutter (Channel master, v1.13.6-pre.25, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.535], locale zh-CN)
    • Flutter version 1.13.6-pre.25 at D:\flutter_sdk
    • Framework revision b7af5e714d (6 hours ago), 2019-12-25 23:49:55 -0800
    • Engine revision 33813929e3
    • Dart version 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.0.0 886615d0f9)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at D:\Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = D:\Sdk
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = D:\Sdk\
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Users\jeff\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[!] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Chrome     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 78.0.3904.87
    • Web Server • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.```
````

desc:[#47820](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47820)

Comment: why doesn't the verbose output show `vscode`? Are you sure you have installed it correctly?

Comment: I have a question about that too, but I'm exactly installed it.

Comment: I had reinstall vscode,and flutter doctor check correct, but the flutter web also can't work property .

Comment: May be print can work fine in android platform only .

Answer (score 0):

Check whether something accidently typed on **filter box** of **DEBUG CONSOLE** in VS Code. A single letter can block entire print outputs.

(know this is an old question, but hope somebody will benifit from it someday)